# getting error InvalidStateError: Failed to set remote answer stable state

Tags: openmeetings

I am getting the following error after when i open the conference room

> InvalidStateError: Failed to set remote answer stable state

I cannot hear the audio and cannot see the video of others who logged in conference. Getting media server of the users failed we ll try to reconnect.

I have installed openmeeting 5.0.X M4 version

Answer (score 0):

You have probably issues with the Kurento Media Server installation. Did you successfully install KMS Server ?